# Prevent page reload when blank link is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a web page to download files using a button.But for some cases the files does not exit and download links are blank...So whenever the user clicks the link page just reloads.It would have been great if i could somehow disable the page reload and display an alert that says file not yet available..

This is the download link button code.row["slink"] gives the download link and may become empty sometime.

```
'<a href="'+row["slink"]+'"><button type="button" class="btn btn-info " data-row-id="' + row.id + '">Download</buttn></a> ';
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which "href" value should I use for JavaScript links, "#" or "javascript:void(0)"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134845/which-href-value-should-i-use-for-javascript-links-or-javascriptvoid0)

Comment: can't you just write an `if` statement above the line which produces this HTML which checked if the URL exists? if it doesn't just don't print the link

Comment: I need to print the link because multiple files are shown on the same page in a table.So if i dont print for one link that will look bad..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if `row['slink']` is present, else replace href with **javascript:alert(...)**(This won't do page reload for blank href, and show an alert):

```
var href = row["slink"].trim().length > 0 ? row["slink"] : "javascript:alert('File Not Yet Available')"


'<a href="'+href+'"><button type="button" class="btn btn-info " data-row-id="' + row.id + '">Download</buttn></a> ';
```

Comment: or add alert `"javascript:alert('No link available.');`

Answer (score 1):

## Simple Solution

You can set target to blank:

```
<a ... ... target="_blank" > ... </a>
```

This will open it in a new tab instead of refreshing.

## More Sophisticated Approach:

You can also use a conditional to build your anchor tag.

```
if (row["slink"] == "")
{
    var atag = '<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="alert(&quot;No File Available&quot;)"><button type="button" class="btn btn-info " data-row-id="' + row.id + '">Download</button></a> ';
}
```

This will give an alert if there is no file.

Comment: This did help me but the alert box didnt show up but the other answer worked great..

Comment: It's the double quotes... silly of me. Will edit. Notice the &quot; values in the alert - the same quotes can't be used within this tag builder code. The &quot; html code will sort it out.